# Abstract Class Array

Tags: java, arraylist, abstract-class

I have four classes. They are: Model, View, Turtle and Sprite. Sprite is an abstract class and Turtle is extended from it. I have worked on this, but I'm stuck and frustrated at my inability to understand this. I desperately need some help understanding what/why to do what is needed.

How do I

> Modify the ArrayList in my Model class to be an ArrayList
>   instead of ArrayList properly and change "setDestination" to
>   use a java.util.Random object to generate a random x coordinate
>   between 0 and the value of the width parameter, and a random y
>   coordinate between 0 and the height parameter. It should then create a
>   new Turtle at the point (x,y) and add it to the ArrayList of Sprites.
>   No longer create any Turtles initially, but only have them created
>   when the user clicks the mouse (i.e. when "setDestination" is called).

Here are my files: (I know it's a lot, but I wasn't sure how much would be completely necessary.)

**Model.java:**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
class Model
{
    private List<Sprite> t = new ArrayList<>();
    private int turtleNumber = 3;

    Model() throws IOException
      {
           for (int i = 0; i <turtleNumber; i++)
            {
              int X = Math.round((float)Math.random()* 1000);
              int Y = Math.round((float)Math.random() *700);
              Sprite t1 = new Turtle(X,Y);
              t.Add(t1);
            }
        }

    public void update(Graphics g)
          {
              for(int i = 0; i <turtleNumber; i++)
              t.get(i).update(g);
          }

    public void setDestination(int x, int y, int width, int height) 
    {
        for(Turtle turt : t)
        {
            Turtle.setDest(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

**Turtle.java:**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

class Turtle extends Sprite
{

    private static int dest_x;
    private static int dest_y;

    Turtle(int x, int y) {
        super( x, y , "turtle.png");
    } 

    public int getX() { return x; }
    public int getY() { return y; }

    public void setX(int xIn) { x = xIn; }
    public void setY(int yIn) { y = yIn; }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        // Move the turtle
        if (x < dest_x) {
            x += 1;
        } else if (x > dest_x) {
            x -= 1;
        }

        if (y < dest_y) {
            y += 1;
        } else if (y > dest_y) {
            y -= 1;
        }
    }

    public static void setDest(int x, int y) {
        dest_x = x;
        dest_y = y;
    }
}
```

**Sprite.java:**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public abstract class Sprite
{

int x;
int y;
String imageName;

Image image;

//Sprite(){}

public Sprite(int x1, int y1, String im)
{
//Store variables
    imageName = im;
     x = x1;
     y = y1;

    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File(imageName));
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Unable to load image file.");
    }

    // Draw the turtle
      g.drawImage(imageName, x, y, 100, 100, null);
}

public abstract void update(Graphics g);

public Image getImage()
{
    return image;
}
}
```

**Controller.java:**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.Timer;

class Controller implements MouseListener
{
    Model model;
    View view;

    Controller() throws IOException, Exception {
        model = new Model();
        view = new View(this);
        new Timer(50, view).start();
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        model.update(g);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        model.setDestination(e.getX(), e.getY(), view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //  Use the following line to determine which directory your program
        //  is being executed from, since that is where the image files will
        //  need to be.
        //System.out.println("cwd=" + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        new Controller();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Modify the ArrayList in my Model class to be an ArrayList instead of ArrayList*" What?

Comment: Also, the code you give does not compile (e.g., `Sprite` is not declared as a class).